# how to validate form validation based on radio button

Tags: javascript, html

i have two radio buttons, one is for fruits and dry fruits. For every radio button i display two text fields, i want to validate these text fields based on the radio button( means based on user which radio button we select). 
I hardly working from morning, any idea.

Comment: Can you show us what have you tried ans achieved so far?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If Radio Button is selected, perform validation on Checkboxes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14321011/if-radio-button-is-selected-perform-validation-on-checkboxes)

Answer (score 0):

Consider following just as example and will help you to sort out your problem

Below code will be part of your HTML

```
<input name="radio_" type="radio" value="fruit" id="fruitRadio" />

<input name="radio_" type="radio" value="dryfruit" id="dryfruitRadio" />

<input name="inputforfruitradio" type="text" value="fruit" id="fruitRadioInputText" />

<input name="inputfordryfruitradio" type="text" value="dryfruit" id="dryfruitRadioInputText" />
```

Above HTML code will need Javascript to work as required

```
$("#fruitInputText").hide();
$("#dryfruitInputText").hide();

$('input[name="radio_"]').on('change', function() {
  var checked_radio = $(this).prop('id');        
  var inputText_id_to_be_shown = "#" + checked_radio + "InputText" ;
  $(inputText_id_to_be_shown).show();
});
```